# SetnavigationBar(this,false) doesn't work on Android in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I want to hide navigation bar with my menu, I can't.
`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`
I want confirmation is that a bug or I something overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't working I'd check to make sure the page you are trying to hide it in is actually being pushed in a `NavigationPage()`.

Calling `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` in cs right after `InitializeComponent();` should work unless something else you have is incorrect.

Or you could instead try setting it directly in xaml of the page with `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`

Comment: Nope, still the same problem. I'm calling a new page like: `App.Current.MainPage = new MainMasterDetailPage(new TestMapPage());` and below InitializeComponent I put `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` nothing really happens.

Comment: Without seeing all your code implementation it's hard to tell your exact issue but is TestMapPage a NavigationPage() that is being set as your MasterDetailPage Detail page? For example something like this `App.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage { Detail = new NavigationPage(new TestMapPage()) };`

Comment: An update with your actual code would be much appreciated.